# Stargazer: decrease number of columns to match amount of dependent variables

Tags: r, regression, stargazer

I have 2 different dependent variables. For each dependent variable, I have 2 independent variables. In total, I have 4 regressions which could be presented in 2 columns. However, when put into the stargazer() -function in R the output is on 4 different columns as follows:

[image]

The code string in R used in this is as follows:

```
Library(datasets)
Library(stats)
#data
data1 <- EuStockMarkets
data1 <- ts(data1)
#lagged values
lags <- lag(data1) 
#whole sample
data <- cbind(data1,lags)
#dependent
x1 <- data[,1]
x2 <- data[,2]
#independent
y1 <- data[,3]
y2 <- data[,4]  
#regressions
reg1 <- lm(x1 ~ y1)
reg2 <- lm(x1 ~ y2)
reg3 <- lm(x2 ~ y1)
reg4 <- lm(x2 ~ y2)
#stargazer
library(stargazer)
stargazer(reg1,reg2,reg3,reg4, type = "text",report = ('vc*t'),omit = c("Constant"),single.row = TRUE, title = "In sample predictability")
```

Is it somehow possible to summarize the stargazer output to only include 2 columns? Namely in this case (referring to the code attached) x1 and x2.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi there, your code isn't very helpful because it is not reproducible - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for help on creating a minimal reproducible example. Good luck!

Comment: Hi @jpsmith! Thank you for the feedback. I adjusted the example to be more clear and reproducible, hope that it would clear up the issue that I am having :)

Comment: Hi! As I understand what you want to achieve, your goal is to have only two columns, one for x1 and one for x2, with each y1 and y2 on their own row. That might not be possible with this type of table, as both y1 and y2 have different values for Observations, R2, etc.; and stargazer tries to show those values so you can compare them.

Comment: Only two columns are exactly what I am trying to achieve @JuanBosco! You are right, I did not realize to take for example the R^2 into account... Thank you for the comment, I'll try to figure something out.